# How to draw a border at the side of the triangle

Tags: windows-phone-8, 3d, directx, hlsl

I'm researching to draw a map route by the D3D. So I have created vertex buffer and fill it by the points: {-0.5, 0.5}, {-0.5, -0.5}, {0.5, -0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}. The Indexes buffer if: {0,1,2, 2,3,0}.
So the rectangle is drown, now I need to draw a border in one pixel. Please give me an idea how to implement it.

Comment: Why not draw lines between vertex instead of one pixel?

Comment: I'll draw a triangle. So the only way is draw lines after triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse your vertex buffer, and set the following on your device context:

```
deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINESTRIP);
```

And then :

```
deviceContext->Draw(4,0);
```

That will draw lines on the rectangle border.

Comment: Advice: to do it you should push-up the z of the vertices, because Z-buffer will suppress your drawings. Thanks a lot the border is drown correctly.

Comment: Good point, was not sure if you were using depth buffer or not. You can also set depth comparison to LESSEQUAL before to render lines as well, generally works pretty well (or set depth bias in rasterizer), so you can keep the same set of vertices.

Comment: How can I change depth comparison?

Comment: This link should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205074(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have tested LESSOREQUAL comparison, it provides less quality than move points by the projection matrix